# Загрузка данных из асинхронной функции в шаблон

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars

Пытаюсь обратиться к mongoDB, а затем загрузить полученные данные в шаблон, но вместо этого получаю долгую загрузку и отсутствие страницы в принципе.

check() - асинхронная, проверяет авторизирован пользователь или нет

```
panel = function(req, res) {    
    check(req, () => {
        console.log("l")
        User.getAllClients(req.cookies.user_id)
            .then((val) => {
                console.log(val)
                res.render("main", {
                    clients: val
                })
                
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                 console.log(err)
            })
    })
    
}
```

Comment: Вангую что случилась ошибка и выполнение попало в блок catch

Comment: @AlexeyTen вот после долгой загрузки появилось в браузере ```It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.```

Comment: В браузере? Что-то вы тут не договариваете… например как это вы из браузера в монгу попали…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ошибся, оно просто долго загружалось а потом сбросилось и вернулось к последнему ответу от сервера.

Comment: Возвращаемся к первому комментарию